# How to prove that the equivalence class of A under the equivalence relation of equipollence is a proper class (NBG)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading a set-theory's chapter in algebra course, which deals with classes, ordinal number.

I have a problems: the equivalence class of A under the equivalence relation of equipollence is a proper class (NBG)?

> $V$ is the class of all sets
>
> if $A,B$ is set, $A\sim B$ $:=\exists f\left(  f\text{ is a map from }A\text{
> to }B\wedge f\text{ is bijective}\right)  $
>
> $\sim$ $=:\left\{  \left(  A,B\right)  :A\sim B\wedge A\in V\wedge B\in
> V\right\}  $
>
> $\sim$ is equipollence and a equivalence relation on $V$
>
> if $A\in V$, equivalence class $\left[  A\right]  =:\left\{  B\in V:B\sim A\right\}  $
>
> Is  $\left[  A\right]$ a proper class ? How to prove ?

Thank you

Comment: It's not a proper class if $A=\emptyset.$

Comment: I was very impressed. I was taught.

Comment: If $A\ne\emptyset$ you can show that $\bigcup[A]=V.$

Comment: I have a question :

Comment: Let $I_{0}=\varnothing$ and $I_{k}=\left\{  1,2,3,\ldots,k\right\}
$....$\left(  k\in\mathbf{N}^{\ast}\right)  $

Comment: then $I_{1}=\left\{  1\right\}  $ and $\left[  I_{1}\right]
=\left\{  B\in V:B\sim\left\{  1\right\}  \right\}  $

Comment: but $\left\{  1,2\right\}  \in V$ not in $\left[  I_{1}\right]  $

Comment: so I can't show that $\cup$ $\left[  A\right]  =V$.

Comment: I don't know if I got it wrong?

Comment: You are right that $\{1,2\}\in V$ and $\{1,2\}\notin[I_1].$ But the conclusion from that is $V\ne[I_1],$ not $V\ne\bigcup[I_1].$

Comment: If $a\in V$ then $\{a\}\in[I_1]$ so $a\in\bigcup[I_1].$